# How to have a chrome extension that have both a popup window and sidebar that only shows on button click

Tags: google-chrome-extension, popup, sidebar, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, screen-recording

I have a screen recording extension that when the user clicks on the start recording button a sidebar shows in chrome broswer with a timer and a stop/pause buttons and when the user click  on stop recording the sidebar closes

just like the quilbot extention that have both popup and sidebar injected to the html DOM

i dont know what to write in both the popup.html and contentscript.js and background.js files in order to inject a sidebar into my chrome browser pages